# Show button if data table rows are empty

Tags: jquery, datatables

We want to show `ADD User` button or link in place of "No matching records found" message if we get 0 records. Also we need pass searched id with the link

How we can implement this.

Ex:

```
------------------------------------------------
                    ADD User link
------------------------------------------------
```

I was trying with :

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(retObj) {
        if(userTable.rows().data().length==0){

        }
 },
```

**Edited:**

```
 var userTable=$('#allUsers').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    'responsive': true,"stripeClasses": [ 'odd-row', 'even-row' ],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [1,2,3,4,5] }
    ],
    "ajax": {
                url: "users_list.php",
                type: 'GET',
                data: userData
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function(retObj) {
        if(userTable.rows().data().length==0){
            console.log("0 records");
        }
    },
    "language": {
        "infoFiltered": "",
        search: "_INPUT_",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search...",
        "emptyTable": '<a href="/path/' + 1 + '">BOOK THIS COURSE</a>'
    },
    "pageLength": 10
    });
```

still getting "No matching records found" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`language.emptyTable`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable) option to define a message when there are no records in the table.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'language': {
      'emptyTable': '<a href="/path/' + 1 + '">Add new user</a>'
   }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/qc2me1gp/) for code and demonstration.

Use can also use [`language.zeroRecords`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.zeroRecords) option to define a message when the table is empty due to filtering.

Comment: Added code. Please refer edited code in question. But still I'm getting "No record found"  message.

Comment: I have added "zeroRecords" instead of "emptytable". Now it is working. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @stefun, I didn't realize you wanted the message to be shown when table is empty due to filtering, added more details to the answer.